# Class library compiling in 3.5 and not in 2.0 - Migrated from Visual Studio 2008 to 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, c#-2.0

I just migrated a class library in FW 2.0 from VS2008 to VS2013.
Problems arrived when I try to compile. In VS2013 it does not work, because it told me that some classes included in  referenced libraries are not present(but they are! I can see the reference)

It only compiles when I set the target FW to 3.5 but  **I should stay with FW 2.0** because Gen.Ico is in FW 2.0.

Remember that in VS 2008 not problems are found.

[image: As you can see it shows an error. Gen.Ico reference is a 2.0 library]

[image]

If i compile it on VS2015 it gives this information:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: A .NET 3.5 assembly should be able to reference and use types from a .NET 2.0 assembly just fine. Are you *sure* the Gen.ICO library is .NET 2.0?

Comment: Completly sure. I want to have both of them in FW 2.0 and VS2013

Comment: Have you tried creating a new .NET 2.0 project and reference the Gen.ICO library from it, does that work? Do you get access to the namespaces and types then?

Comment: Yes, it does not work neither

Comment: Is it a public available assembly?

Comment: No sorry, is private. I attach a screenshot of the Fw of gen.ico.dll

Comment: OK, can you execute `ildasm` on it? check the manifest node and the Metadata version, what does it say?

Comment: let me a minute. i will try

Comment: The MANIFEST node shows a yellow text page, the topmost line should be something like `// Metadata version: v...........`, that's the line I'm interested in.

Comment: // Metadata version: v2.0.50727

Comment: It uses Enterprise Library 4.0 . Not sure if that will affect in VS2013

Comment: OK, next, is the class library you're compiling a normal .NET class library, not a portable one, or a silverlight assembly, or something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114633/discussion-between-badulake-and-lasse-v-karlsen).

Comment: VS2013 is *much* better at checking that *all* assemblies you have a dependency on conform to the framework target version.  In VS2008 you could easily add an assembly like Gen.Ico that has a dependency on a 3.5 assembly like System.Core.  And never get a peep at compile time.  And never at runtime either, nobody ever actually has a machine with *only* 2.0 installed.  Fwiw, don't rely on IntelliSense squiggles, actually compile it to get an MSBuild diagnostic in the Output window.

Comment: Yes, is there where I found the error. Intellisense AND Output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:
Performing some investigation in Gen.Ico.dll I found that it references some libreries using FW 3.5 so:

- VS 2013 / 2015 is much better in checking problems with referenced libraries, and it will throw errors and warnings that VS2008 won´t.
  If you reference some library that inside  references libraries from other frameworks, as this case 3.5:

Gen.Ico references a Library that references:

```
    .assembly extern System.Core
     {

     .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )     //.z\V.4..
     .ver 3:5:0:0

     }

     .assembly extern System.Management.Instrumentation
     {
        .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 ) // .z\V.4..
        .ver 3:5:0:0
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you right click on the project and choose Properties, in Applicaiton, you can choose which framework you want to target. Choose Framework .Net 2.0 and it should work.

Comment: Yes I can , but as i said "I should stay with Fw 2.0, it`s a rule."